# Function not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var outerFn = function ( oParam ){

                return oParam;  
        }

        var v = OuterFn( 2 );
        alert('V :'+v);
    }
```

**In this function i always get OuterFn not defined. Whats going wrong ??? Can somebody tell me.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OuterFn and outerFn are different things as JavaScript is case sensitive, try it with a small o. Ie:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var outerFn = function ( oParam ){

            return oParam;  
    }

    var v = outerFn( 2 );
    alert('V :'+v);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function is assigned to `outerFn` variable, so that's why you should call it:

```
var v = outerFn(2);
```

JavaScript is case sensitive.